# Exporting all rules in SonarQube

Tags: export, sonarqube, rules

I need to export all rules by language. I can get a set of 100 rules from the web API for a given language, but it seems the web API is limited to paging through the rules 100 rules at a time. Obviously I can set the pagesize higher (i.e. 500) but what about rule sets that have more than 500 rules (i.e. Java)? Do I need to page through the rules until the end? How do I tell when I have the last page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and see: https://sonarqube.com/api/rules/search?languages=java,js , returns the list of rules for *Java* and *JavaScript* . Response starts by:

```
{
"total": 537,
"p": 1,
"ps": 100,
"rules": [...] // 100 items
}
```

The rest of it is just good ol' maths: 537 items in total, page sizes of 100. So, all things considered, page 6 should be the last one: https://sonarqube.com/api/rules/search?languages=java,js&p=6 - 37 rules returned, job is done (and incrementing further `p` would anyhow only give you an empty JSON back.

Comment: It would be nice if there was an option to list them all. I have to do this for every language X number of pages in the language. I have other work to do...

Comment: You do realise that this is an API right ? Pagination is a pretty standard thing (see [here](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/), or [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/pagination-in-the-rest-api)). Takes one line of code to loop through the pages if needed.

Comment: Yes, I realize it's an API. Doesn't mean you can't have a parameter that allows for skipping the pagination. There are plenty of web pages that have "Show all" as an option. What I was really hoping is that someone (Sonarqube) would chime in with "Well, to export them ALL you need to do this..."

Comment: Sorry, but as told by Nicolas, pagination cannot be removed. You can always set the 'ps' parameter to the max value (500), but that's all. And you can use the 'p' field from the response to know the number of pages you need to go through.